# How to use a hyperlink to access only one sheet of another workbook

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I hope you can please help me with this. I'm pretty new with Tableau.

I have a workbook already done in Tableau Server, and I'm trying to create a link to be able to access just 'one' worksheet of another workbook. This other workbook has more than 10 worksheets, and I just want to limit the access to a single worksheet without having to copy the workbook or worksheet. I'm not too sure if this is even possible... I couldn't find a way to do it.

Any advice would be great! Thank you all